# Oracle SQL Conditional aggregate function in group by query

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, aggregate

I'm trying to write a query that will aggregate data in a table according to a user-supplied table that drives the aggregations.  I got it to work fine when I  just used a sum statement, but when I put the sum inside of a case statement to allow the user to specify sum, count, mean, etc., I get group by errors.

I replaced:

```
 sum(column)
```

with:

```
 CASE b.calculationtype
      WHEN 'SUM'                  THEN SUM(column)
      WHEN 'MEAN'                 THEN AVG(column)
      WHEN 'COUNT'                THEN COUNT(column)
      WHEN 'VARIANCE'             THEN VARIANCE(column)
      WHEN 'STANDARD DEVIATION'   THEN STDDEV(column)
 END
```

Does Oracle see beyond the case statement when evaluating the group by function or am I out of luck trying to make the actual aggregation function change based on the value in table b?

I could always brute force it the long way and move the calculationtype logic outside of the actual query, but that seems a little painful in that I'd have 5 identical queries with different aggregate functions that are called depending on the calculation type field.

```
   select b.REPORT,
          case b.AGG_VARIABLE_A_FLAG
           when 'N' then null
           when 'Y' then a.AGG_VARIABLE_A
          end,
          case b.AGG_VARIABLE_B_FLAG
           when 'N' then null
           when 'Y' then a.AGG_VARIABLE_B
          end,

          --<<< problem starts >>>

          case b.CALCULATIONTYPE
           when 'SUM' then sum(a.column1)  when 'MEAN' then avg(a.column1)  when 'COUNT' then count(a.column1)  when 'VARIANCE' then variance(a.column1)  when 'STANDARD DEVIATION' then stddev(a.column1)
          end,
          case b.CALCULATIONTYPE
           when 'SUM' then sum(a.column2)  when 'MEAN' then avg(a.column2)  when 'COUNT' then count(a.column2)  when 'VARIANCE' then variance(a.column2)  when 'STANDARD DEVIATION' then stddev(a.column2)
          end

          --<<< problem ends >>

     from DATA_TABLE a
             cross join CONTROL_TABLE b
    where a.ID = bind_variable_id
          and a.SOURCEARRAY = b.SOURCEARRAY
          and b.CALCULATIONTYPE <> 'INTERNAL'
    group by b.REPORT,
          case b.AGG_VARIABLE_A_FLAG
           when 'N' then null
           when 'Y' then a.AGG_VARIABLE_A
          end,
          case b.AGG_VARIABLE_B_FLAG
           when 'N' then null
           when 'Y' then a.AGG_VARIABLE_B
          end
```

Comment: Have you considered adding b.CALCULATIONTYPE to the 'group by' statement?  In the above extract it is missing.

Comment: For example, with the calculation type as sum, I would expect the following: 
(REPORT, sum(x1), sum(x2), sum(x3)...)
With the calculation type as mean, I would expect the following output:
(REPORT, avg(x1), avg(x2), avg(x3)...).
The report name has the type of output it is (as well as other fields).  I'm trying to have one query aggregate the 30 or so fields based on the chosen aggregate function rather than having 5 queries, once for each function. Basically, I took a working query that had sum(column1), sum(column2), etc. and changed that to case calculationtype... Does that help? Thanks

Comment: Hi Pham, that's what I want (value1 can be sum or mean or count).  The table identifies the type of output with other fields.  It's a reporting table that my users go to for output from my process.

Comment: lol Koen, That did it. (facepalm) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `b.calculationtype` in `GROUP BY` clause.